# Paypal Sandbox using selfsigned certificate

Tags: c#, soap, paypal

can anyone confirm that paypal sandbox accepts selfsigned certificates?
i have a piece of code (soap integration) that was working fine on my test environment. now it stopped working. i'm aware of the fact that paypal requires TLS1.2 but i'm hoping that their sandbox allows self signed certificate.
Anyone can confirm it?
thanks

Comment: From: https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/ -> 'Any tests that are currently run against PayPal Sandbox endpoints will require a VeriSign G5 root certificate, so you can test your upgrades by making requests against the Sandbox environment by using the following steps'